# Text goes missing with jquery .insertBefore()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting started with JQuery, and I've built a little js function that adds fields to a form when it gets called.

```
function newPoint(time){
    $('<br/>At '+ time + ' seconds, bring object <select><option>in</option><option>out</option></selection> at <select><option>regular</option><option>slow</option><option>fast</option></selection> speed.<br/>').insertBefore('#submitBtn');    
}
```

Here's the html...

```
<div id="rightSide">
<form> <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Go"></form>
</div>
```

When the function runs, the insert works but the word 'at' in between the drop downs and the word 'speed' at the end don't get inserted.

[image]

Why is this? I imagine I'm misunderstanding something pretty key to the way jquery or js works. (I'm just getting my feet wet.) If that's the case, can you point me in the right direction of understanding, rather than just helping me figure out the issue here?

Thanks!

Edit: With that fixed (stupid fingers), another question pops up...

When I remove the line break <br/> at the beginning of the insert, I lose the text up to the the first drop down box. Any thoughts on why that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:
`... bring object <select><option>in</option><option>out</option></selection> at ...`

That last closing tag says `</selection>`. It should be `</select>`. The same problem exists at the end of your insert string.

Comment: Aha, how embarrassing. *blush*

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opening a `select` tag but closing a `selection` tag?

Beaten by moments.

Comment: Beaten by even more moments hehe